# is there a like that hadith?

Tags: hadith

I remember reading somewhere hadith where prophet Muhammad (pbuh) said that there are 71 or 70 different kinds of sons of Adam (pbuh) including (yajooj and majooj) only one of them will go to heaven. The one will go will be us. While yajooj and majooj are going to hell.

I wonder if I'm misremembering the hadith or I mixed up some hadith. If anyone knows about it tell me please.

Comment: This sounds a bit  mix of different narratives and misunderstanding there's a hadith about 72 sects of Islam and only one of them entering janah. How this is related to yajooj and majooj is unclear to me

Comment: There is a another Hadith in Sahih Bukhari where the Prophet mentioned that 99 out of every 100 will go to Hell but most of them are from the tribes of Gog & Magog.

Comment: @Ahmed If you have the answer can you share the hadith?

Comment: @Hegao https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4741